# My worpress search page is showing no results

Tags: php, posts, pages, search

I want to display the publications searched for via `searchform.php` in the `search.php` page but it does not work ...

The search is done well when I look at the url (ex: New World):
`http://localhost/?post_type=post&s=New+World`

But I have nothing displayed on the results page, I fall directly into the `else`.

Here is my code:

```php
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('content', 'search'); ?>
                            <?php include("assets/php/posts.php"); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                      ...
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What is in `assets/php/posts.php`? From the name (plural) it sounds like it's something that does it's own loop. That could be confusing things.

Comment: is this the entire template? What does the rest of the file look like?

Comment: My file "post.php" is the content that will be displayed in a loop.